# What's the appropriate SE site for a question about Google+?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I initially asked my question on sof, which I now realize is clearly the wrong place:

> So, as the title indicated - someone who is not my friend, neither to whom I am following, +1'd my post on google+, how could I then go follow him or add him to my circles? I got the notification, which shows the person that did the +1, but there is no link for me to access that person's profile page. And I searched the person by name, tons of having the same name!

I'm trying to post it on the correct site now, so I thought it best to ask here rather than risk adding noise in the wrong place again.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/839601)**

Answer (score 6):

Questions about **Google+** (assuming you're *not* talking about the Android or iPhone app) are on-topic at [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus).

Your question, as written, may not do very well however. There needs to be some more descriptive detail of the issue. Screen shots would be awesome.