# What is the appropriate title of the my following question to post in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, title

There is a problem, I want to find a solution. But I can't. So I want to post it in [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). But I'm confused about the title. What is the appropriate title of the following question?

> Four teams A, B, C, and D should be allocated rooms in a hostel. Each member will have separate room. Each team has K members. It is entrusted that there are 4K side-by-side rooms in one long corridor of your hostel. Teams A and B have both requested that each member of their team should have another member of their own team in an adjoining room (the room to the left or right). Teams C and D do not trust each other and have both specifically requested that no member of their team should be put up in a room with a member of the other team in an adjoining room. 
>   In how many ways 4K rooms can be allocated to them?

Comment: That question should not be posted on Stack Overflow. When you actually try to solve it and get stuck on some part of the solution, then you could _maybe_ ask about that part on either [SO] or [math.SE] depending on the nature of the part you're stuck on.

Comment: Actually i've no idea how to solve this problem

Comment: Then you should have asked which is the appropriate site to ask this question with the tag [site-recommendation] like this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245038/whats-the-appropriate-se-site-for-a-question-about-google

Comment: This looks like a homework question, please note that Stack Exchange is ***not*** a homework completion service.

Answer (score 5):

This is a question in Combinatorics, not in programming, so it shouldn't be posted to StackOverflow at all. However, it does seem very appropriate for [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/), which has [more than 13K questions tagged with combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics).

As for titles, I think something down the lines of "find the number of combinations to host 4 teams, with restrictions" should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a lot like a homework question. Not only is it a homework problem, but you said yourself you have no idea how to start. I suggest that part of the problem with not being able to come up with a title is that you want to ask somebody to just do your problem for you. That isn't how any site on the SE network works.

You need to do some research on your own. I assume your course has given you materials on how to solve these sorts of problems. You need to go over those materials and find out what concepts are being employed here. Then you will have a better idea how to ask a a more specific question.

It's totally okay (on the appropriate site, which might not be Stack Overflow in this case) to ask conceptual questions about algorithms, but you need to work through the problem at least enough to have an idea what the concepts involved are and what part of them you don't understand. Your question should show what parts of the problem you've figured out and what step you are stuck on. It should ask for how to fix that step, not for somebody to do the whole problem for you. Once you get to that point a title will come quite naturally.